# Rails 4: Validate file, then import if conditions met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, import

I am importing a file using SmarterCSV and I have 1 function that validates certain aspects of the file, and then redirects you, displaying the results.

I would like this display to also include a button that says "import", which allows you to import that same file as long as you are satisfied with what is displayed.

**How can I pass the file to the second function after redirect without having to select the file again?**

```
# validate file and check display
def check_file
    @success, @error = Timecard.check_timecard(params[:file])
    redirect_to timecards_path, notice: [@success, @error]
end

#import into database if display is satisfactory
def bulk_upload
    x = Timecard.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to timecards_path, notice: "Times imported successfully."
end

#view showing display
<% if flash[:notice].is_a? String %>
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
<% elsif flash[:notice].is_a? Array %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Regular</th>
                        <th>Overtime</th>
                        <th>Sick</th>
                        <th>Vacation</th>
                        <th>Holiday</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% notice[0].each do |success| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="color: green"><%= success[0] %></td>
                        <% success[1].each do |type| %>
                        <td><%= type %></td>
                        <% end %>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>
                    <% notice[1].each do |failure| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="color: red"><%= failure[0] %></td>
                        <td><%= success[1] %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-xs-center">
                <div class="card card-nav-tabs">
                    <div class="header header-info">
                        Import Timecard and Send Email
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">

                      <!-- IMPORT GOES HERE -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way to do this. You should move the file to a location within your application and then, store the path of the file in the database against the record you are trying to upload this file to. Consider the following example. Assuming you are uploading this file to a TimeCard record and an instance exist as **@time_card**

```
name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
directory = "public/images/upload"
path = File.join(directory, name)
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload][:file].read) }

@time_card.csv_path = path
```

Then, redirect the user to the validation error page. Then, after use submits the page you can import the CSV using the file in **@time_card.csv_path**

Comment: I guess Im a little confused about how to implement the above code

Comment: I got it to save the file, but the file it saves is empty.  In other words, the original file's contents are not being written

Comment: I found that this solution worked: 

`tmp = params[:my_file_field].tempfile
destiny_file = File.join('public', 'uploads', params[:my_file_field].original_filename)
FileUtils.move tmp.path, destiny_file`