# Rails 4: Convert string to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, object

So I am trying to pass a file to a function but the file is in the format `"#<File:0x007ff043273040>"` so when I try to call the function I get an error: `undefined method 'tempfile' for "#<File:0x007ff043273040>":String`.

Some additional code:

```
def self.import(file, timecard)
    n = SmarterCSV.process(file.tempfile, options) do |array|
        array.first[:employee_id] = Employee.find_by(user_id: array.first[:user_id]).id
        array.first[:payroll_id] = timecard[:payroll_id]
        Timecard.create( array.first )
    end
end 

def bulk_upload
    x = Timecard.import(params[:file], params[:timecard])
    redirect_to timecards_path, notice: "Times imported successfully."
end
```

**How can I remove those quotation marks that it gets treated as a file?**

Comment: Looks like at some point you've cast the file to a string, do you have a copy of the code you're trying to execute?

Comment: It's a little complicated because I am trying to pass the file from the `params`.  I have the path if there is a way to turn the path into a file object

Comment: Can you include some other code?

Comment: Sure, in the above code, when I call the `import` function, `params[:file]` is already a string.  In a previous function, I call `params[:file].tempfile` on the file object.  Perhaps thats when it becomes a string?

Comment: Somehow you are passing `"#<File:0x007ff043273040>"` to the params, is that coming from a browser? It is very strange that params[:file] is a String like that. Did you maybe overwrite it somewhere?

Comment: So as seen in another question I posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461894/rails-4-validate-file-then-import-if-conditions-met) I upload the file to one function, validate the file and display results, then attempt to pass the file to this `import` function